# How do I prevent jquery from reloading an animation in IE mouse hover?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have an animation that plays on mouse over on a containing div. In IE9+ if the user hovers over an element inside that container it replays the animation.

My basic setup is:

```
<div class="book">
    <img src="bookcover.jpg" />
    <div class="overloay">
        <p class="title">Book title</p>
        <a href="#">read book</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user hovers over "book" the overlay and it's elements animate into view. In IE9+ the elements reset and animate again. I've tried putting a stopPropogation on the mouseenter and mouseleave events but that has no affect.

I can't really create a jsfiddle since the person who built it used a unique animation library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the developer was using `mouseover` and `mouseleave`. I didn't notice that until I had him review his code with me. Of course this was causing a trigger every time the mouse moved. Changing `mouseover` to `mouseenter` solved the issue.